# Error: A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: flutter

[when I run the code it gives me the error shown in picture I don't find any answer for this question here. help me out with this flutter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5iVM.png)

Comment: Hello, please see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What code? What are you trying to achieve?!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.